# Should a comma be used between "us" and a noun describing "us"?

Tags: commas

Example: When she needed help moving, she asked us four men.  When she needed help moving, she asked us, four men.

Comment: I know that this sentence should not have the comma, but I would be very interested to know why. The [rule of essentialness](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/596/1/) seems to be a guideline at best.

Comment: No, definitely not. "Us" is a 'personal determinative' here that denotes a set containing the speaker. So the object of the verb "asked" is the noun phrase "us four men". Strictly speaking it should be the nominative "we", not accusative "us", but the latter is found, as your example shows. If a comma is used, "us"/"we" becomes a pronoun and the NP is then appositive, as in We, the club's loyal supporters, are in agreement with the directors ..._ But in your example, "us/"we" is clearly a determinative, so no comma is required.

Answer (score 1):

Without the comma, *four men* is restrictive, i.e., defining.  The sentence means

> She asked these four men and not some others.

With the comma, *four men* is nonrestrictive, i.e., supplying extra information.  The sentence then means

> She asked this group, who, by the way, happened to be all men.